# Importing output from two seperate lines from textfile and turning them into variables in Python

Tags: python, io, readline

I have a python script that outputs EX. "Gender: Male" and "Age: 25-32" on seperate lines in a textfile. This same script can print out different ages and male and female gender based on the facial recognition application. I need to RETRIEVE these seperate lines and convert them into variables. This is what I have so far.

```
    infile = open('output.txt', 'r')

    g_line = infile.readline()
    a_line = infile.readline()

    with open('output.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        g_line = myfile.readline()
        a_line = myfile.readline()
    print(g_line)
    print(a_line)
```

Comment: try eval this can evaluate your lines into runnable code. You have to modify the lines when you want to use eval() :)

Comment: @Strider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: yes eval = evil :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file looks like:

```
Gender: Male
Age: 25-32
```

Try:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    gender = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip()
    age = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip()
    print(gender) # Male
    print(age) # 25-32
```